# Using TextEdit for HTML editing

Tags: macos

When I edit any HTML file (e.g. `Untitled.html`) using TextEdit and save it, it saves a file named e.g. `Untitled.txt` automatically and removes the `Untitled.html` file. How can I prevent this from happening?

I followed [these steps](http://support.apple.com/kb/ta20406) to setup HTML editing in TextEdit, but no use.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? You want to edit HTML files using WYSIWYG or do you want to edit the HTML code directly?

Comment: I am trying to edit html directly

Comment: I can reproduce it on OS X Lion. This is really stupid... Seems like a genuine bug though, not much you can do except report it to Apple and hope for the best.

Comment: yes mine is os x lion. How do we report to apple?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/

Answer (score 0):

OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) appears to have a checkbox setting that would be helpful if selected:

TextEdit > Preferences > Open and Save

When Opening a File:

[checkbox] Display HTML files as HTML code instead of formatted text

(This is a later version than discussed earlier but could be helpful to others with similar or related problems.)